# How to set up internal custom domain in front of aws lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have situation where i need my lambda in AWS to run on custom internal domain? I really don't know where to start. I have A virtual private cloud (VPC) setup and my lambda runs inside, also i have internal URL setup in Route53, but I don't know how to glue the two together. I want to invoke my lambda when someone call this internal URL. any suggestions on what i should do.

Comment: You can configure API gateway as a trigger to your lambda function.

Comment: Typically you would use CloudFront and serve your Lambda function as an API via API Gateway. See if this is helpful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create an internal API, You can deploy the API in the aws API Gateway. you will also need to explicitly set the endpointType to private.

Steps:

#### Deploy your api (as private)

by default all the api gateway apis are public. you should explicitly deploy your api as private by setting the `endpointType` attribute to `private`. 
you will also need to create a resource policy for the API to create a private api.

#### Create private VPC Endpoint for API gateway

You need to create a private VPC endpoint because you can only access the private API through the private vpc endpoint.

**remember:** if you do this step, all of your other public APIs accessible only though their custom domains.

#### attach the VPC endpoint to your private API

you need to attach the vpc endpoint to your api

#### Accessing the private api

you can only access through the private api through the private vpc endpoint.

```
curl https://vpce-07f635e4b63555555-abcwdo3f.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.vpce.amazonaws.com/development/hello -H 'x-apigw-api-id: abcdefg2k8'

#VPC Endpoint DNS URL: https://vpce-07f635e4b63555555-abcwdo3f.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.vpce.amazonaws.com
#API Stage: /development
#Endpoint path: /hello 
# Your rest api Identifier: abcdefg2k8
```

Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/

#### Custom dns name for `private vpc endpoint`

you can create a custom domain name from `Route53` to point to the `private vpc endpoint` url by creating an Alias record.
Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-vpc-interface-endpoint.html

Comment: sorry had to write a lot

Comment: remember: if you do this step, all of your other public APIs accessible only though their custom domains? do you mean all APIs related to this domain or all lambdas that has been generated on this account

Comment: Let's say you have few public APIs in your AWS account. Now you are introducing a private API. From now on you can access the public APIs only if they have a custom domain such as apis.mydomain.com/orders. You can't use Amazon created DNS to accept public APIs anymore. Hope it's clear

Comment: got it. thanks for clarification. and by the way i setup everything but create custom API on top AWS generated API. i have already private URL that that is used internally between servers. what i am missing how i can make my custom internal URL to resolve to amazon generated URL.

Comment: I haven't done this part. I use the `public dns url` of the `private vpc endpoint`, so that it will resolve everywhere. but looks like there is a way to setup a custom dns.  updated my answer

Comment: awesome that exactly what i was looking for?, that make sense actually, to use vpc endpoint DNS value and create an alias in Route 53 to route traffic to vpc endpoint. before when API is public i used cloudfront id for API and create an alias in Route 53 to route traffic to it, i guess this it is private now i could use VPC endpoint instead. thanks that was very hopefully